# What is the best way to implement two custom dialogs, one after the other?

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog, customdialog

through the help of various tutorials, I've managed to write a custom dialog that displays a listview populated by records from a local database. I have set click listeners and figured out how to retrieve the record at the listview item clicked by setting the cursor at the position returned and so on...Now what I want to do is, dismiss this dialog when an item is clicked, and automatically open a new dialog with this cursor's content as the name of the table from which to re-populate the new listview. I'd like to know if anyone knows the best way of doing this in terms of application structure.
Currently, I am calling my dialog to show in my Activity like this:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.pickerbutton:
        showDialog(DIALOG_PICK_CATEGORY);
        break;
    }
}
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    dialog = null;
    switch(id) {
    case DIALOG_PICK_CATEGORY:
        CustomDialogList.Builder customBuilder = new
            CustomDialogList.Builder(SendCookieActivity.this);
        customBuilder.setTitle(R.string.category);
        dialog = customBuilder.create();

        break;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

After this dialog is shown, the user picks a category from the CustomDialogList dialog. I am having a hard time thinking of how to make it so that after the category is picked, this dialog is dismissed (or looks like it's dismissed) and the same one with newly populated items appears (or can be a completely new dialog too). and when someone presses the back button, the previous dialog is shown. Think of it as a file explorer but with only two levels of depth. I'd like to keep using my CustomDialogList because I have customized its look to match everything else in my app. Perhaps what would help me with this problem besides or instead of code, would be some diagrams of how this type of UI flow has been implemented before along with some pseudo code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your custom dialog extends `Dialog` (or one its sub-classes). Have your `Activity` implement `DialogInterface.onDismissListener`. Then after you create the dialog with...

```
dialog = customBuilder.create();
```

...use `dialog.setOnDismissListener(this);` before you show it.

Your `Activity` will have to implement...

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    // Identify which dialog was dismissed and do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have had to do this in the past, I have the onCancel for the dialog open the new dialog.